# Convert Javascript response to Array/Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, elasticsearch

I have the following response from a Javascript ElasticSearch Query, and i need to map it to the below structure.  Is there a more efficient way to do this than what I am currently doing?

Thanks

**Structure I need to map to:** (about 700 of these)

```
[{
    "coordinates": ["48", "37"],
    "name": "something",
    "population": "501"
},
```

**Current structure of my data being returned:**

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

0: Object

 _id: "4"
 _index: "locationIndex"
 _score: 1
 _source: Object
   coordinates: Array[2]
       0: -77.080597
       1: 38.892899
       length: 2
       __proto__: Array[0]
 name: "someName"
 population: 57205
1: Object
 ...
```

**What I'm trying but fails:**

```
 var results= [{
                "key": 'coordinates',
                resp.coordiantes[0],
                resp.coordinates[1],
                "key": 'name',
                resp.name                    
                })
            }];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your data is stored inside a `myData` variable, you can use the `Array.prototype.map` method to manipulate it and achieve what you want. Here's a solution:

```
result = myData.map(function(obj) {
    return {
        coordinates: obj._source.coordinates,
        name: obj.name,
        population: obj.population
    }
});
```

Simple as this! The result will be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "coordinates": [-77.080597, 38.892899],
        "name": "some name",
        "population": 52701
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [-54.930299, 30.992833],
        "name": "some name 2",
        "population": 84229
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [-82.001438, -5.38131],
        "name": "some name 3",
        "population": 5991
    } //, ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't quite understand Object syntax in Javascript; in order for my answer to make the most sense, you may wish to [read up](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) a little on them.

Now that you understand Objects more, it should become quite clear that what you want looks something like:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var resp = data[i];
    results.push({
        'coordinates':resp['source']['coordinates'],
        'name':resp.name,
        'population':resp.population
    });
}
```

For bonus points, you could include a JS framework like jQuery and just uase a [`map` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

Comment: Actually the native JavaScript `Aarray` object already has a `.map` method.

Comment: It depends on browser support. I still have to deal with companies that use IE8, which, as an example, doesn't `support [].map()`. :)

Comment: I usually tend to drop support to IE, but you can always define it by yourself as a fallback: `if (!Array.prototype.map) Array.prototype.map = function(callback) { for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) this[i] = callback(this[i]); };`

Answer (score 1):

I like Marcos map solution the most but also possible and quick is to use `Array.from(data)`. This helped me in the past to convert the response API data that should be an array but wasn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the open source project http://www.jinqJs.com.
You can easily do something like this to do what you want.

```
var result = jinqJs().from(data5).select(function(row){
    return {coordinates: [row.coordinates[0]['0'], row.coordinates[0]['1']],
            name: row.name,
            population: row.population
           }
         });
```